# ST_DistanceSphere very slow after Postgres/PostGIS upgrade

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We've been using Postgres 9.6 and PostGIS 2.4.1 successfully on [Compose](https://www.compose.com/) for several years, but the service is shutting down so we're trying to move to Google Cloud and Cloud SQL. Our Cloud SQL instance is running Postgres 14 and PostGIS 3.1.4. The new database has more CPU, disk, and memory than the old database.

We've exported the data from Postgres 9.6 (Compose) like this:

```
pg_dump -h <ip> -U <username> -p <port> -d <database name> > data.sql
```

and imported it like this to Postgres 14 (on Google Cloud):

```
psql -U <username> -h <ip> --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f data.sql
```

This works without any errors.

The problem is that when we run queries such as the one below, in parallel, around 5/s, it's really slow on Postgres 14/PostGIS 3.1 (Google Cloud):

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere('SRID=4326;POINT(13.154672331767976 55.673222697684935)'::geometry, mt.geofence) AS distance
FROM my_table mt 
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere('SRID=4326;POINT(13.543852374474474 55.93984692695315)'::geometry, mt.geofence) <= 2000
ORDER BY distance;
```

There are roughly 13100 rows in `my_table`. In our old database, queries like this took roughly 200-300 ms, but it can take up to 4 seconds in our new database.

We have an index defined like this (in both the new and old DB):

```
CREATE INDEX geofence_index ON my_table USING GIST (geofence);
```

Running `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` on Postgres 9.6/PostGIS 2.4.1 returns:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Sort  (cost=6085.40..6096.24 rows=4338 width=8) (actual time=204.360..204.361 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                  |
|   Sort Key: (_st_distance('0101000020E61000003C143D36314F2A40A8BD4E292CD64B40'::geography, geography(geofence), '0'::double precision, false))                                 |
|   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                                                         |
|   Buffers: shared hit=1392                                                                                                                                                     |
|   ->  Seq Scan on my_table mt  (cost=0.00..5823.32 rows=4338 width=8) (actual time=95.714..204.330 rows=1 loops=1)                                                         |
|         Filter: (_st_distance('0101000020E61000008B7084D173162B40444173E74CF84B40'::geography, geography(geofence), '0'::double precision, false) <= '2000'::double precision) |
|         Rows Removed by Filter: 13033                                                                                                                                          |
|         Buffers: shared hit=1389                                                                                                                                               |
| Planning time: 0.626 ms                                                                                                                                                        |
| Execution time: 204.404 ms                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN 10
Time: 0.261s
```

Running `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` on Postgres 14/PostGIS 3.1.4 returns:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Gather Merge  (cost=257890.05..258183.87 rows=2555 width=8) (actual time=1893.020..1919.665 rows=1 loops=1)                                                  |
|   Workers Planned: 1                                                                                                                                         |
|   Workers Launched: 1                                                                                                                                        |
|   Buffers: shared hit=1591                                                                                                                                   |
|   ->  Sort  (cost=256890.04..256896.42 rows=2555 width=8) (actual time=1834.941..1834.943 rows=0 loops=2)                                                    |
|         Sort Key: (st_distance('0101000020E61000003C143D36314F2A40A8BD4E292CD64B40'::geography, geography(geofence), false))                                 |
|         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                                 |
|         Buffers: shared hit=1591                                                                                                                             |
|         Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                                                      |
|         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on my_table mt  (cost=0.00..256745.43 rows=2555 width=8) (actual time=1290.257..1834.816 rows=0 loops=2)                   |
|               Filter: (st_distance('0101000020E61000008B7084D173162B40444173E74CF84B40'::geography, geography(geofence), false) <= '2000'::double precision) |
|               Rows Removed by Filter: 6516                                                                                                                   |
|               Buffers: shared hit=1533                                                                                                                       |
| Planning Time: 0.212 ms                                                                                                                                      |
| Execution Time: 1919.704 ms                                                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN 15
Time: 2.055s (2 seconds), executed in: 2.053s (2 seconds)
```

FWIW we've tried running `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();` (twice) in the new DB if there's some data that needs to be upgraded, but this has had no impact on query performance.

What could be causing the query to be slow in Postgres 14/PostGIS 3.1.4 and how can it be solved?

Comment: "around 5/s"  What if you just run one at a time?  Are they only slow when you try to run 5/s?

Comment: Your query explicitly casts to geometry, but your plan shows geography.  I don't see how it is possible for your shown plan to come from your shown query.

Comment: `st_distance` or `st_distanceSphere` in the `where` clause will always be slow as it is not using the index and will compute the said distance to every row. Instead, use [`st_dwithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

Comment: @jjanes Yes, if I only run the query without load then it takes 200-300 ms (like it does in our old DB). We can see that the CPU of the new DB spikes if we increase it to ~5/s. And I can assure you that the results of "explain" literally is for the query I pasted above.

Comment: @JGH We need to calculate the distance, so I assume that st_dwithin won't work?

Comment: The usual way is to compute the distance in the `select`, and use `st_dwithin` in the `where` clause. Doing so will filter candidate points using a bounding box (fast!), and will then refine and compute the true distance only for these candidates. When computing the distance directly in the where clause, the distance to every points in the dataset is computed, which is slow.

Comment: @Johan perhaps st_dwithin with geography columns? can you check this link? https://dbfiddle.uk/hNaRTlPq

Comment: @JimJones I've managed to change the query to use "st_dwithin" instead, I think it uses the index now. However, it's still slow if we have parallel requests. I think the problem is that we need to perform the ST_DistanceSphere calculation regardless. I suspect that even though st_dwithin uses the index, ST_DistanceSphere needs to be calculated (which is expensive) for all rows due to "order by". This seems to be the case even though I add a LIMIT.

Comment: @JimJones We also require "spherical" calculations, e.g. st_dwithin requires true as the fourth parameter (which will make it slower ifaik).

Comment: If it is fast in isolation and only slow in concurrency, I would say the most plausible explanation is just that you misestimate how much CPU capacity you are renting and how it will behave under contention.  What if you try other queries not involving postgis which are about the same load (like counting rows from a 3 million row skinny table) and see how those behave under concurrency?